# Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server:

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am moving the sonarQube from an old server to the new server.

While doing so I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project ags-probe: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

my pom is :

```
<profile>
        <id>sonar-new</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>https://newServer.com</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.login>xyz</sonar.login>
            <sonar.projectKey>key</sonar.projectKey>
            <sonar.projectName>name</sonar.projectName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar-old</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>http://oldServer.com</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.login>xyz</sonar.login>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar-local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<properties>
   <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.5.0.1254</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

I am trying to use the `sonar-new` while currently it is on `sonar-old`

The command I am running is `mvn install sonar::sonar -P artifactory,sonar-new`

While  `mvn install sonar::sonar -P artifactory,sonar-old` works perfectly fine.

Comment: You want to use https. Then you have to inform Java see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html) for a starting point on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the certificate that you are using for the new sonar server url https://newServer.com. Just export the full certificate chain for the certificate you have on your new server. Then import the certificate using the java keytool into your cacerts file:

```
keytool -import -alias your-certificate-alias -file your-certificate-file -storetype JKS -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Use $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts for java versions up to 8.