# How to export the full certificate chain for SonarQube?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, certificate

I am facing the error while trying to do a maven-sonarqube scan

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project Gloria: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57426760/20885032), but how to export the the certificate? From where? Can someone please explain this more lucidly.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://docs.mend.io/en-US/bundle/wsk/page/how_to_resolve_error_message__pkix_path_building_failed__sun_security_provider_certpath_suncertpathbuilderexception__unable_to_find_valid_certification_path_to_requested_target_.html) gives the proper and full answer

First you will need to create a certificate. To do that follow these steps:

> 1. Open an HTTPS connection to the URL (i.e https://www.example.com/,
>    https://saas.whitesourcesoftware.com/ in the browser
> 2. Press F12 to access the browser’s Developer Tools
> 3. Go to the ‘Security’ tab
> 4. Click ‘View certificate’
> 5. In the Certificate details window, go to the ‘Details’ tab
> 6. Click ‘Export’
> 7. Make sure the file format is: ‘Base64-encoded ASCII, single
>    certificate (*.pem, *.crt)’
> 8. Name the file: Windows: ‘whitesourcesoftware.com.crt’ (Mac OS:
>    ‘whitesourcesoftware.com.cer’)

Comment: thank you!!!!!! I've been battling with this since last night until I found this post. God bless you man!